# Cookies should be set if specified cookie is not set, yet code ALWAYS creates new cookies

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I want a script that firsts verifies that `$_COOKIE['location']` is set. If `$_COOKIE['location']` is not set, I want to save the entrance URL into `$_COOKIE['EntryURL']` and set `$_COOKIE['location']` to 'TRANS' while redirecting user to enter their zip or manually select their location.

So I have generated the following PHP:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['location'])) {

    $EntryURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if($EntryURL == '/') { 
        $EntryURL = '/index.php?pg=Home'; 
    }

    setcookie('EntryURL', $EntryURL);
    setcookie('location', 'TRANS');
    header("Location: MYSITE/index.php?pg=" . urlencode('Please Select Your Location')); 

}
```

The problem that I am encountering, however, is that all of this code is being executed with or without `$_COOKIE['location']` being set. The page opens, sees `$_COOKIE['location']` is not set, sets `$_COOKIE['EntryURL']` and sets `$_COOKIE['location']` and properly redirects.

However, on the redirect page (which is included from the index, meaning that the same code will be called again) it STILL executes the same script, generating a second cookie for each and prevents the redirect code on my location query page from working properly (as it is accessing the `$_COOKIE['EntryURL']` which has been rewritten, rather generated again as it is saved twice, to reflect the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` from the location page.

I CANNOT understand how it is possible to execute this code block with or without location cookie being set. Hopefully I am doing something stupid that someone can quickly identify.

Comment: The workaround in the accepted answer here might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738593/check-if-a-php-cookie-exists-and-if-not-set-its-value

Comment: That in no way answers this problem. That person is trying to recall a cookie set on the same page, that is not what I am doing here.

Comment: What if you gave it an expire time? For example using `setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");`

Comment: It doesn't matter when it expires. In fact, I specifically want to go back and save these cookies for like six months so that the person does not have to reset their location each time they visit the site, provided they do not clear their history. My problem is that this code executes before the cookie exists and then again after it exists.

Comment: You didn't happen to disabled cookies while testing, did you?

Comment: The cookie is saving twice, cookies work.

Comment: On the next page, you are checking that the cookie does not exist, correct?

Comment: The code above is at the top of my index page, so it will be called on every page I make. It should only execute if `$_COOKIE['location']` is not set. When it executes, it should set the cookie (and it DOES) it is just that on the next page, it executes the same code and recreates cookies, now with a bad redirect url...

Comment: Have you tried echoing out the `$_COOKIE['location']` in your loop? Or in an `else` statement?

Comment: Post a screenshot of cookies in dev tools.

Comment: Not completely sure what you are asking me. But, I actually look up the cookies stored in the browser. I have deleted them and tried to echo `$_COOKIE['location']` before and there is nothing there. I have stripped everything out so that it would echo 'cookie is there' or 'cookie is not there'. It is able to identify if the cookie is there or not. Yet when the page redirects, it write the cookies again. So on my location page, I have two cookies each of location and entryurl.

Comment: pmahomme, you want me to show the cookies as they are actually stored on my computer from the browser?

Comment: Check out this solution given here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15703487/failing-to-set-cookies-in-php?rq=1

Comment: I have screen shots, but I'm new, I don't know how to upload. lol

Comment: You can add the images to your question

Comment: it won't upload the pictures, and really, I don't know why it matters. I delete cookies. there are no cookies. cookies work. I open the root of my site. I have two location cookies and two entryurl cookies.

Comment: Have you tried to use the 4th argument of `setcookie`? Pass "/" for that to make sure your cookie is available across your domain, and not only on the current location (which is the default): `setcookie('EntryURL', $EntryURL, 0, "/");`

Comment: that should not matter as I am not leaving this directory, ever. every page on my site is generated from /index.php

Comment: i am not sure (I am no expert), but i think adding the fourth argument would overwrite the cookies so that i would not get duplicates, but they would still be wrong.

Comment: But my question was: have you tried...

Comment: actually, to clarify, i have a process.php to execute scripts between pages if needed. but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: for the sake of the argument, i just set those parameters, exact same results, which is why i had not tried that previously, it has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: i was wrong about overwriting the cookies, actually, there are still two of each.

Comment: Ryan, the cookies are retrievable on the page that it is redirected to. I can't test to see if they come back before the if because they do not exist before then.

Comment: @BJC I can't reproduce this by putting the code you've provided on two separate pages and running them. Only one version of each cookie. What browser are you using?

Comment: Post the screenshots here: http://imgur.com  and post the links.

Comment: i am currently testing this in firefox. i want to make sure i am being clear that each page is /index.php?pg=1 and /index.php?pg=2 etc. but that should not matter. i have even tried setting the cookies and redirecting to a third page just to redirect back to the second in case i was trying to recall the cookie too fast. i have no idea what is happening.

Comment: i guess this is what you want to see: http://imgur.com/a/ktEMp

Comment: the first EntryURL cookie is the correct URL location. the second is wrong as it is grabbing the url of the redirect page, which should not happen, because that code should not execute when a location cookie set.

Comment: also odd to me, if the code is executing again, it should be getting stuck in an infinite loop, and that isn't happening...

Comment: if feel like everyone has given up on me. lol. but here is the even more effed up thing. i put a script to send me an email that says 'cookie not set' from within that loop and i loaded my webpage. i received 3 emails.

Comment: So it's going into a loop... have you tried using two separate files, going from the index to file2? And seeing what happens with that?

Comment: So, I have asked my index page to simply connect to database, insert a line of text into a sql database and die(); it does this three times. and that is before I even get to the loop. I just die() at the top of the page after the connection and it is being loaded 3 times. WTF?

Comment: Hmm... Try not redirecting from this page and just create the cookies in the if statement.  Then try loading the page from your url by typing it back in on your browser.  What happens if you do that?